# need help about my javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently trying to match all words in a HTML text and wrap each one in a `<span>` tag.

My problem is when a word has a trailing apostrophe as shown in the following text snippet:

```
seconds’
```

The trailing apostrophe part is not being matched.

I need to include the trailing `'` characters as part of the word.

This is the regex I have tried:

```
([^\r\—>< \/]+(?!\>))(\b)
```

and [this](https://regex101.com/r/b8O33w/1/) is my online test.

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm proposing something quite different to match all the words in your example :

`([\w’]+?)([\s—,]|<br>)`

This regexp has 2 matching groups, what you need is the results in the first group (the `([\w’]+?)` part). It matches any word-character (`\w`) OR the `’` character. You can add any other char you want to include in here.

The second group is used as a separator. It matches any whitespace character (`\s`), a `,` or a `—`, or the string of characters `<br>`. You can add any separator you need in here.

Here it is in action, printing every word of your example :

```js
var myString = "<br> With sixty seconds’ worth of distance run, <br>Yours is the Earth and everything that’s in it, <br> And—which is more—you’ll be a Man, my son !</p>"
var myRegexp = /([\w’]+?)([\s—,]|<br>)/g
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString)
while (match != null) {
  console.log(match[1])
  match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem `\b` quantifier will match non alphanumeric and then the backtick is the border. You can change for one optional backtick and then the next whitespace becomes the border. [Like this](https://regex101.com/r/b8O33w/3/)
`(([^\r\—>< \/])+(?!\>))(?=\b)[’]?`

For more info on `\b` in ECMAScript look [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.6)
and [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary)

Comment: yes but it doesn't match some word like And, More and some chars like , are include in word now :(

Comment: You're right about `\b` preventing the match of the `’` character, but your solution doesn't work well in his linked example (it doesn't match well the part with `And—which is more—you’ll`)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can mock `\b` behavior using `(?=[\s—-])` instead:</strike>

```
([^\r\—>< \/]+(?!\>))\/]+(?!\>))(?=[\s—-])
```

See [demo.](https://regex101.com/r/Tqpduo/1)

`[^<>,\s—]+?(?!>)(?=[\s—,])` is working [on your test](https://regex101.com/r/0lZYOm/1). You may need to update the last lookahead to meet your needs.